# Threads in for loop not working correctly

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop

I want to make a program that gets the ids from a database and create a thread with the same function for each id. It works, but when I add a while loop to the function it only hangs there and doesn't get the next id's.

My code is:

```
void foo(char* i) {
    while(1){
        std::cout << i;
    }
}

void makeThreads()
{
    int i;

    MYSQL *sqlhnd = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(sqlhnd, "127.0.0.1", "root", "h0flcepqE", "Blazor", 3306, NULL, 0);

    mysql_query(sqlhnd, "SELECT id FROM `notifications`");
    MYSQL_RES *confres = mysql_store_result(sqlhnd);
    int totalrows = mysql_num_rows(confres);
    int numfields = mysql_num_fields(confres);
    MYSQL_FIELD *mfield;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(confres)))
    {
        for(i = 0; i < numfields; i++)
        {

            printf("%s", row[i]);

            std::thread t(foo, row[i]);


            t.join();


        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    makeThreads();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Thanks

Comment: The thread will never join since its execution never ends. The problem is there imo.

Comment: Do you know what `join` call, on the thread does (e.g. in `t.join();`)? It suspends blocks thread, and waits for the `join`ed thread (`t`) to terminate. And, as written, it never does. Such functionality would have been obvious, if you read the documentation for [`std::thread::join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join), or stepped through your code in a debugger.

Comment: what do you expect from a loop `while(1){ std::cout << i; }` other than hanging, or what is the output you expect?

Comment: As @Stephan said: That's cruelty to CPU's! You should be fined for that.

Comment: Right, so the code doesn't get executed since the thread doesn't get terminated. Is there any way that it creates a new thread and join that in the for- loop?

Comment: @Test Once again, do you understand what `join` does, and can you explain, why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop in question currently creates one `thread` object and one thread. Period. `join`ing hides this problem in a way by forcing the main thread to wait for the thread to run to completion. That the thread can't is another issue.

Creating a thread and immediately `join`ing forces your program to run sequentially and defeats the point of using threads. Not joining the `thread` will result in Bad because the `thread` object will be destroyed at the end of the loop and the `thread` has not been detached. [Destroying an undetached thread is bad.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) `std::terminate` does pretty much what it sounds like it does: It hunts down and kills Sarah Connor. Just kidding. It ends your program with all the subtlety of a headsman's axe.

You could detach the threads manually by calling `detach`, but that's a really, really Bad Idea because you lose control of the thread and your program will exit while the threads are still running.

You need to store these threads and `join` them later, after the loop that spawns them.

Here's a simple approach to do that:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for(i = 0; i < numfields; i++)
{
    std::cout << row[i];
    threads.push_back(std::thread(foo, row[i]));
}
for (std::thread & t: threads)
{
    t.join();
}
```

Now you will have `numfields` threads running forever, and I'm sure you can take care of that problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

`t.join();`
Means the program waits here for the thread t to finish.
Since:

- t executes foo
- foo never ends, due to while true

Then: you never execute the instructions after the join

So you have the uninterrupted 111111